# jsp forward tag is not working in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have made a `login page` and a forward tag is not working it creates error which i can not able to find out.

I uses access **database** and after clicking sign in button it will check, if user is already registerd then page should forward next page but it does not so.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="login.jsp" method="get">
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <td><br>
        <label>EmailID:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="emailid" maxlength="50" size="30">
    </td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td><br>
        <label>Password:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="password" name="passwordid" maxlength="50" size="30">
        <p>
        </p>
    </td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="sign in"></center></td>

    <%
    try
    {

    String existemail="registration",existpass="12345";

    ResultSet rs, rs1;
    String emailid1=request.getParameter("emailid");
    String passwordid1=request.getParameter("passwordid");
    if(emailid1.length()!=0 && passwordid1.length()!=0)
    {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:collegep");

    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    rs=st.executeQuery("select password from collge where
    email='"+emailid1+"'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
    existpass= rs.getString(1);
    }

    if(existpass.equals(passwordid1))
    {


    <jsp:forward page=
    "afterlogin.html" />


    }else
    { %> invalid combination of email and password<%
    }

    }
    else
    {` %>
    <div id="error">all field must be filled.</div>
    <%
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    %>
```

Comment: It seems `</tr></table>` before it was not there, so the jsp-forward falls into limbo. Maybe look at the HTML source in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing from:

```
<jsp:forward page:
```

to:

```
<jsp:forward page=
```

Comment: the following error are arises.Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s),Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression,/Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment/Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statemen/forward cannot be resolved to a variable/The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void/Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you used inappropriate Scriplet Tags(<% %>)..close scriptlet end tag(%>) above ur `<jsp:forward page="afterlogin.html"/>`

All java code should be in Scriplet Tag only..and html code outside of it..make this changes